# Creating JavaScript file instead of TypeScript with ng new command

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I want to use JavaScript in my new Angular 2 project and use `ng new` command for bootstrapping. But this command creates TypeScript files and I couldn't find any command line option to use JavaScript instead. How can I do that?

Comment: @Scott Selby, why remove the good will messages? We are not robots.

Comment: speak for yourself , a lot of us are robots

Comment: But I ask my question to humans. =) So if a hi or thank you is not a waste-of-time, I prefer to write it. Leave them where they are or show a rule against them. Thank you!

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115694/why-is-saying-thank-you-in-question-undesirable

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't see any rule there.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3021/194720

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the current state of the CLI generating JS files and not TS files is not possible.

In the future custom blueprints will be supported in which case you can create your own.

Comment: So, is there any feature request about custom blueprints?

Comment: Yes, https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6593#event-1112149055